# Iterate over spring' session scoped beans

Tags: spring

I have a session scoped bean. This bean have an ID. It is possible to have just one ID (session scoped bean) at a given same time, so I won't "login" with the same ID in another browser?

The easy way is to have a singleton bean and every time a new ID log in I will register it in a List, so I will have a List of every single ID that is logged in the webapp, but I think Spring will have a register of every session scoped bean too.

It is possible to iterate over the session scoped beans registered by Spring?

Comment: What information do you want to get from such a register? I think your idea of storing such information in a singleton scoped bean is fine.

Comment: I want to access the "ID" of the scoped beans. Does Spring has a register of these beans? I think it will be more efficient and reliable to access Spring' own register of beans.

Comment: if you could use spring-session, all these spring session scoped beans will be stored as attributes in the sessionRepository